# Why javascripts don't work on iphone safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

three days already trying to solve problems with this scripts and right now I see that this scripts don't want to work in phone. These script must close iframe then clicking on modal or icon .close. It perfectly works on PC but not on iphone. Also adding codepen and webpage https://codepen.io/jokbas-rklys/pen/zJaxQN www.thehoney.lt Maybe someone know the solution?

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById('popupBoxOnePosition');
var modal2 = document.getElementById('popupBoxTwoPosition');
var modal3 = document.getElementById('popupBoxThreePosition');
var modal4 = document.getElementById('popupBoxFourPosition');
var exit = document.getElementById('close1');
var exit2 = document.getElementById('close2');
var exit3 = document.getElementById('close3');
var exit4 = document.getElementById('close4');


// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == modal2) {
    $('.iframe2')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == modal3) {
    $('.iframe3')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    modal3.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == modal4) {
    $('.iframe4')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    modal4.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == exit) {
    $('.iframe1')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == exit2) {
    $('.iframe2')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    modal2.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == exit3) {
    $('.iframe3')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    modal3.style.display = "none";
  }
  if (event.target == exit4) {
    $('.iframe4')[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    modal4.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: The safari is DRY

Comment: This is maintainance hell. You should use loop or something that smart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure why the window.onclick event is not triggering on those modal popups.

One thing I noticed in the codepen HTML is that you have window.onclick = function in two places. This is not why closing the modals is not working, but just so you know you can not have two window.onclick callbacks - the last one will overwrite all previous ones. If you want several `onClick` calbacks you have to use `window.addEventListener('click', function);`. This way you can attach multiple events on a single DOM element (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).

On your issue as I mentioned above I could not realise why it's not working without investing too much of my time into it.

I would however take a slightly different approach to attach those `onClick` events to close the modals:

```
$('.modal').on('click', function (e) {
  var $this = $(this);
  var $target = $(e.target);
  var $iframe = $this.find('iframe');

  if (!$target.is($iframe)) {
    $iframe[0].contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"' + 'stopVideo' + '","args":""}', '*');
    $this.fadeOut(100);
  }
});
```

This way you're attaching the `onClick` listeners directly to the modal popups and the `click` events do not have to propagate (bubble) up the DOM chain. My best guess is that the `click` events are being interrupted somewhere and never reach the `window`. I'd suggest reading up on event bubbling as it's often the cause of why events attached to either `window`, `document` or other DOM element higher up the DOM tree do not fire (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#Event_bubbling_and_capture).

I've also shortened the logic as compare to your `onClick` function. As we attach the `onClick` events directly to the popups we know exactly which popup was clicked (the popup that was clicked is assigned to `this`). All we need then is to check if we clicked on the `iframe` and if not stop the video and close the modal.

To be fair (and clear) we don't even have to check if we clicked on the `iframe` because the click events on the `iframe` are also being stopped and will actually never propagate to the popups. I've added that check for future reference so it's clear how to check what we clicked on.

Hope this helps.